# laravel after signup giving error in builder.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I am beginner in laravel. I just created a new laravel 5.4 project. Then I run

```
php artisan make:auth
```

After that I try to register the user. 
Now I am getting this error:

```
ErrorException in Builder.php line 2443:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getAuthIdentifierName() (View: D:\wamp\www\crud\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)
```

It looks to me as error is coming from welcome.blade.php

```
@if (Route::has('login'))
    <div class="top-right links">
        @if (Auth::check())
            <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
        @else
            <a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a>
            <a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a>
        @endif
    </div>
@endif
```

I have created a Models folder inside app copied User model inside this folder.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{.....
```

I did make change in my auth.php file

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
```

Can anybody help me solve my problem.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't need to change auth.php for applying User table for login check, by default User table is scanned for Auth. 

Normal `php artisan make:auth` would work properly without any change.

Answer (score 0):

- Try add a backslack `@if (\Auth::check())`,
- or make sure your user model uses `Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable` trait,
- or if you have changed your User's model class namespace (from `App\User` to `App\Models\User`), try to run `composer dumpautoload`.

Let me know if any solution work.